# How Can I Let Users +1 a Google Plus Page and log them out immediately?

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-activity, google-plus

I am attempting to integrate Google+ in my android app but I am stuck. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class GooglePlusActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "GooglePlusActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;
public ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public static String accessToken;
public static String email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.google_plus);
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)

            .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
                    // .setScopes("profile")       // alternative basic login scope
            .build();


    // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

    TextView gplus_header = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ft_header);
    gplus_header.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.ft_main_header)));

    mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
    mPlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPlusOneButton.setSize(600);

    WebView gplus = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.gplus_zoom);
    gplus.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    gplus.setInitialScale(500);
    gplus.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    gplus.zoomIn();
    gplus.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


}

@Override
public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent){
    if(!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {

        mPlusClient.connect();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.plus_one_button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SmakActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    mPlusOneButton.initialize("https://www.google.com/+Simpledeveloper", PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    mPlusClient.connect();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
        // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
        // connection dialog.
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
    // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
    mConnectionResult = result;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
        mPlusClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
    email = accountName;
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    task.execute();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
    mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
    //GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(this, accessToken);
    Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + accessToken);
}

AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                    GooglePlusActivity.this,
                    mPlusClient.getAccountName(),
                    "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
        } catch (IOException transientEx) {
            // Network or server error, try later
            Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // Recover (with e.getIntent())
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            Intent recover = e.getIntent();
            startActivityForResult(recover, 0);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
            // The call is not ever expected to succeed
            // assuming you have already verified that
            // Google Play services is installed.
            Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
        }

        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
        accessToken = token;
    }

};
```

}

Now, I want to handle the onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) event but I don't know how to do that. I basically want to know whether a user has clicked the **OK** button on the pop up dialog box (for +1). I would like to start a new activity as soon as the user has Plus One'd the Google page.

Besides that, I want to clear the token or logout the user completely so that a second user can come in and do the same thing as the first person - which means they should be asked to Login without their credentials being remembered. In Facebook Android sdk, you clear session. I don't know how to do that in Google+.

Every help, hint is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why in onConnected you do .disconnect() ?

Comment: That is how the documentation showed how to do it; once you retrieve what you need, there is no need to keep a connection I suppose!

Comment: Ok:). Have you tried to revoke the access and disconnect to "clear session" ?:)

Comment: I already solved this problem using an alternative solution. Thanks for your help